# How to make 2 cells update based on each other in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet tracking expenses for a trip where each row is some category (hotels, travel, food, etc.). I want two columns to see the amount of money going to this category (like $100 for food) and the % of the total trip cost (if the trip cost $1000 then for food this would say 10%).

I can do this with a super simple formula in the % column if I only need to enter the amount of money for each expense and vice versa, but I want to be able to enter either a total amount of money or a percentage and have the other update accordingly. Trying to just do this with two dependent formulas gives a circular dependency.

link to sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RV4u_sB8ZhjEXRn1z9_FFNb8UvWSpNjWOqcFQ6yiEM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RV4u_sB8ZhjEXRn1z9_FFNb8UvWSpNjWOqcFQ6yiEM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- from the drop-down menu select the symbol you want to work with
- then enter the amount of money you have in total
- next add items and respective amounts
- everything else is auto-calculated

  [image]

- ### **[editable demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eVwwRSo3UNO10gcDLWfTELIWQiuNjGyZlOv6vcHXxCs/edit#gid=0)**